# Submitting a form through AJAX (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I want to send information from a form through AJAX but on submit, none of the message i want to appear pops up.
My initial thought was that it had something to do with the readyState which should be equal to 1 from the initialisation of 'xhttp' but instead is equal to 0 shown by the console log.
However I'm not proficient enough with the AJAX maneuvers to solve the issue.

To summarise what I'm trying to accomplish through this, the user inserts the name and surname of the player he wishes to seek the stats for. If he exists, then 'nice' appears (in the original code, i have my own things),  if else the long french sentence pops up.

```
    <div>
        <form name="infoJoueur">
            <label for="nomJoueur"> Nom: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="nomJoueur" id="nomJoueur" required><br>
            <label for="prenomJoueur"> Prénom: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="prenomJoueur" id="prenomJoueur" required><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Rechercher les statistiques du joueur">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="stats"></div>
    <script>
            var formElement = document.forms[0];
            formElement.addEventListener("submit", function () {
                /*Gets the name and surname from the form*/
                var surname = document.getElementById("nomJoueur").value;
                var name = document.getElementById("prenomJoueur").value;

                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                console.log(xhttp.readyState);    //result: 0
                console.log(xhttp.status);        //result: 0
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { 
                        document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                console.log(xhttp.readyState);     //result: 0
                console.log(xhttp.status);         //result: 0
                xhttp.open("GET", "/TPNote2/afficherStatistiques.php?nomJoueur="+surname+"&prenomJoueur="+name, true);
                xhttp.send();
            }, false);
        </script>
```

Here I've included the '/TPNote2/afficherStatistiques.php' page

```
<?php
        //Opens up a .csv file to check if the player belongs to the list
        $file = fopen("infoJoueur.csv", "r");
        if ($file) {
            $verif = false;
            while($joueur = fgetcsv($file, "1000", ";")) {
                if ($_GET["nomJoueur"] == $joueur[0] && $_GET["prenomJoueur"] == $joueur[1]) {
                    $verif = true;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);

        if ($verif) {
            echo "nice.";
        } else {
            echo "Le joueur n'appartient pas à la base de donnée. Veuillez vérifier l'écriture de son nom et prénom ou vérifier son existence.";
        }
    ?>
```

There seems to be an error message but it flashes too quickly on the console for me to screenshot it and read it.

Comment: Try logging information from inside the `onreadystatechange` handler. Log `this.readyState` and `this.status`, see what they are.

Comment: Yeah i do get the wanted 4 and the 200 inside the onreadystatechange which means my supposition was wrong so now im even more clueless to where the problem is

Comment: Actually it would mean the problem is in the server side ( '/TPNote2/afficherStatistiques.php') of the thing

Comment: Parameter 2 of `fgetcsv()` should be an integer so `1000` not `"1000"`. No idea if that is serious enough to cause the error though. Take a look at [the fgetcsv manual page, there is a nice example there too](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: Check the network tab in your browsers developer tools when making the ajax request to see what the request looks like and what it actually returns.

Comment: Yeah I understood that after El_Vanja's comment

Comment: Next step: logging `this.responseText` in the console.

Comment: You should also [url encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the values in the variables before you're using them in the `open()` function.

Comment: _Another small point_ You dont create the variable `$verif` until you are inside the `if ($file) {` but if `$file` is false you still attempt to use the variable that does not exist yet. Move the `$verif = false;` to before the first IF

Comment: update: i do actually see a flash of the echo written but it disappears in an instance (like if  there was an instant refresh of the page)

Comment: Did you look at the PHP Error log on the server?

Comment: If you see a flash, then that means something else edited the content of that HTML element. Can you check the Network tab if multiple requests might be happening?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're not preventing the default submit. So it would make sense that the page actually refreshes.

Comment: I've got 3 requests with 2 pendings... 2 of first php and 1 of the second php

Comment: Right that makes sense... silly of me